# How to change test-unit version on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, unit-testing, insoshi

I'm trying to install insoshi on my Linus OS. When I try to run the command "script/install", it returns this error:

```
Creating empty files.  Please ignore permissions error messages.
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: can't activate test-unit-1.2.3, already activated test-unit-3.1.5
/home/james/insoshi/lib/tasks/rspec.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/james/insoshi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load'
/home/james/insoshi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `block in load_with_new_constant_marking'
/home/james/insoshi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/james/insoshi/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load_with_new_constant_marking'
/home/james/insoshi/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/james/insoshi/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:8:in `each'
/home/james/insoshi/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/james/insoshi/Rakefile:10:in `<top (required)>'
```

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

How do I change the version of test-unit? Bundler does not work, and I am unable to find a problem in the rake file.

Comment: remove new version and install old version would fix your error

Comment: That still is not doing anything. I keep receiving the error message.